# Python send email from a csv list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am new to python and am trying to read values send email using smtplib. Here is the format of my csv file -

```
Name,Email,Message  
A,a@email.com,Message1  
B,b@email.com,Message2  
C,c@email.com,Message3
```

I need to come up with a Python Script that reads the csv columns and sends out emails to each member from the email column with corresponding Message text in the email body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume you're using Python-2.x.

You can use the `smtplib` module to send the email and the `csv` module to read the csv file.

Besides, to use `smtplib`, you must have a email address used to send the emails, no matter the email is Yahoo mail or Gmail or whatever else.

Some sample codes read as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.Header import Header

def sendmail(info_list):
    msg = MIMEText(info_list[2], "html", "utf-8")
    msg['Subject'] = Header("YOUR SUBJECT", "utf-8")
    msg['From'] = "FROM_WHOM@XXX.com"
    msg['To'] = info_list[1]
    s = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.XXX.com")
    s.ehlo()
    s.starttls()
    s.login("YOUR EMAIL USERNAME", "YOUR EMAIL PASSWORD")
    s.sendmail("FROM_WHOM", info_list[1], msg.as_string())

def main():
    with open("msg.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
        msg_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        msg_reader.next()
        map(lambda x: sendmail(x), msg_reader)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I Using above code only one Problem I have face mail not sent until I converted in list map(lambda x: sendmail(x), msg_reader)

Answer (score 2):

Python comes with a great module called smtplib. It is used for Simple Mail Transfer Protocols.

```
import smtplib
sender = 'from@fromdomain.com'
receivers = ['to@todomain.com']

message = """From: From Person <from@fromdomain.com>
To: To Person <to@todomain.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
"""

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
   print("Successfully sent email")
except SMTPException:
   print("Error: unable to send email")
```

Code credit http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm

Answer (score 2):

SMTP is a great module, but not so user friendly.

[yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail) tries to make it all a little easier.

In your case I would use:

```
import yagmail

yag = yagmail.Connect('username', 'password')

with open("msg.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    csv_reader.next()

    for line in csv_reader:
        for name, email, message in line.strip().split(','):
            yag.send(email, subject = name, contents = message)
```